# How to drag-n-drop links/pages via the jQuery plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, drag-and-drop

Hi I'm doing a self-project on creating a jQuery UI to allow users to drag-n-drop links/webpages, specifically, articles from Wikipedia, to a sort of 'organizer' like the stacks in Solitaire. I'm hoping to add various features such as when the user drag-n-drops the Wikipage to the UI such as grouping items/card visuals.

I'm unsure where to start as I'm relatively new to jQuery. Is it possible to drag a page from Wikipedia and drop it in a jQuery UI? If anyone has any advice, that would be awesome as I'm really trying to figure out how to kick this thing off the ground.

---

Edit: Anyone? I've had no luck finding anything yet.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**EDIT 2:**

I rewrote this in pure JS form (also fixes some issues).

Gist: https://gist.github.com/matt-curtis/9044134

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/z9Y86/1/

Code:

```
var LinkGrabber = {
    textarea: null,

    /* Textarea Management */

    attach_ta: function(){
        if(LinkGrabber.textarea != null) return;

        var textarea = LinkGrabber.textarea = document.createElement("textarea");
        textarea.setAttribute("style", "position: fixed; width: 100%; margin: 0; top: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0; left: 0; z-index: 99999999");
        textarea.style.opacity = "0.000000000000000001";

        var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
        body.appendChild(textarea);

        textarea.oninput = LinkGrabber.evt_got_link;
    },

    detach_ta: function(){
        if(LinkGrabber.textarea == null) return;
        var textarea = LinkGrabber.textarea;

        textarea.parentNode.removeChild(textarea);
        LinkGrabber.textarea = null;
    },

    /* Event Handlers */

    evt_drag_over: function(){
        LinkGrabber.attach_ta(); //Create TA overlay
    },

    evt_got_link: function(){
        /* THIS IS WHERE WE HANDLE THE RECEIVED LINK */

        var link = LinkGrabber.textarea.value;

        alert(link);

        LinkGrabber.detach_ta();
    },

    evt_drag_out: function(e){
        if(e.target == LinkGrabber.textarea) LinkGrabber.detach_ta();
    },

    /* Start/Stop */

    start: function(){
        document.addEventListener("dragover", LinkGrabber.evt_drag_over, false);
        document.addEventListener("dragenter", LinkGrabber.evt_drag_over, false);

        document.addEventListener("mouseup", LinkGrabber.evt_drag_out, false);
        document.addEventListener("dragleave", LinkGrabber.evt_drag_out, false);
    },

    stop: function(){
        document.removeEventListener("dragover", LinkGrabber.evt_drag_over);
        document.removeEventListener("dragenter", LinkGrabber.evt_drag_over);

        document.removeEventListener("mouseup", LinkGrabber.evt_drag_out);
        document.removeEventListener("dragleave", LinkGrabber.evt_drag_out);

        LinkGrabber.detach_ta();
    }
};
```

**Original Answer:**

> The only POSSIBLE solution I can think of is to do something that uses
>   an input or textarea to get the link of the dropped anchor, because
>   inputs and textarea(s) receive the links of dropped links as text.
>
> HTML:
>
> ```
> <textarea id="link_grabber"></textarea>
> <div id="notice">Drop a link on me! :)</div>
> ```
>
> JS:
>
> ```
> $("body").bind("dragenter dragover", function(){
>     //When the user has dragged a link into the document...
> }).bind("dragleave dragexit", function(){
>     //When the drag is moved outside the document...
> });
>
> setInterval(function(){
>     if($("#link_grabber").val() != ""){
>         var val = $("#link_grabber").val(); //Get the newly dropped link
>         $("#link_grabber").val(""); //prep textarea for the next link
>         $("#notice > span").text("Your link is: "+val);
>     }
> }, 100);​
> ```
>
> I made a jsFiddle that demonstrates the concept:
>   http://jsfiddle.net/C8yAa/2/
>
> **EDIT:** There is also an HTML5 way of doing this, check this out: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/dnd/basics/

Comment: Holy crap you coded something for me! This is so interesting. Could you explain more on 'using an input to get the link of the dropped anchor'? I assume that 'link' now holds the URL; perhaps we could use it to create a drag-and-droppable object, though I would not know how to go about this.

Comment: It works because when a link (bookmark, etc.) is dropped onto a textarea or input, that link will appear in the textarea or input. The example works by creating a textarea at the lowest opacity possible: 0.01. Then, I created an interval that continually checks to see if something has been entered in the textarea, aka our dragged & dropped link. Once that happens, I alert the link and clear the textarea for use again.

Comment: Thanks this will be helpful to me. :)

Comment: very smart use of CSS :) +1

Comment: A better version of this would skip setInterval at all (self-note)

Comment: @Jean-NicolasBoulayDesjardins (that is the longest username I have ever seen, just typing it has me winded) I've re-written this, check out the update.

Comment: @mattsven Where? I went to: http://jsfiddle.net/C8yAa/256/ but it still redirects.